# Constantly checking for button press while executing other code?

Tags: python

I need to be able to stop a robot with a button press.
I have made the proof of concept and I am able to stop the program with the button press, but, I only know how to do one thing at once.

Here is the code that I've made:

```
buttons = Button()
while buttons.backspace != True:
    time.sleep(.1)
else:
    #I guess I need to handle some kind of cleanup here too
    pass
```

This should be run while other code is running. How can I do this?

Comment: What library is that `Button()` function coming from?

Comment: Also, if you can split up the "other code" into bits that each take under 100ms, you can just do one of those bits inside the `while` loop and it'll work fine. Maybe not the _best_ design, but pretty simple.

Comment: It's coming from `ev3dev-lang-python`.

Comment: One more thing: `while: … else:` is only useful if you have a `break` inside the `while` body, and some cleanup code you only want to execute if you exited the loop normally rather than via `break`. If you have cleanup code you want to run no matter what, use a `with` statement.

Comment: I don't think I can do that. The program may crash, and it would be cool to recover the robot without calling another python script that cleans up and stops the motors.

Comment: Which part don't you think you can do?

Comment: Dividing the whole program in smaller blocks. It's not designed to be that way and the program needs to be ready in an hour.

Comment: Anyway, I know nothing about this library, but in general: (a) If it has a way of running an event loop (like Tkinter, asyncio, etc.) or timed frame loop (like PyGame), you probably want that. (b) If not, if it's thread-safe, you may just want a background thread to poll the `Button()`.

Comment: Why can't you divide the whole program into smaller blocks? I'm not talking about entirely separate programs, just little functions that you call one after another.

Comment: The documentation has 'event handlers' although I have no idea on how to use them (http://python-ev3dev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/other.html#button). Regarding dividing in blocks, I may run a motor and wait for it to stop (for example), this means that putting a check on every motor movement might not be enough, especially if the program somehow crashes.

Comment: have you tried threads?

Comment: @DiegoContreras Nope, I don't understand them very well. I don't know how the structure would be with threads in this case.

Comment: I'll write an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have what's commonly called an "Interrupt", so we will place it on a function to call it on a Daemon Thread (Which is always running), at it will look something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
buttons = Button()

def checking_interrupt():
    global buttons
    while not buttons.backspace:
        time.sleep(.1)
    else:
        #I guess I need to handle some kind of cleanup here too
        pass

Thread(target=checking_interrupt).start()
```

Here i didn't specify that it was a daemon thread, but you could, just passing a boolea true on "daemon" at your object Thread constructor.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to make another method for the actual code and call both with `.start()`?

Comment: Nope, your code can run in the "main" thread, and this will always be checking on your buttons, in parallel.

Comment: Alright. I used a function to stop the motors (which it does it seems) and an exit() but the program keeps running nonetheless.

Comment: what do you mean with "the programs keeps running"? you mean you want your code to exit? can you paste more of your code please?

Comment: Nvm I fixed this by using `os._exit(0)`